# Post on next page not showing in my blogger third party template

Tags: templates, blogger

I'm using 3rd party template in my blogger. it seems to be working great only that when I click the NEXT page after the main page (which shows 7 posts). it only shows 3 posts which are also repetition from what I already have on the main page.

I don't have much knowledge in programming, just very basic. please help.

my blogger site is www.kikayinside.com

Answer (score 0):

Find this in template (Dashboard - Template - Edit HTML):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var pageCount=3;
var displayPageNum=6;
var upPageWord ='&#171;';
var downPageWord ='&#187;';
//]]>
</script>
```

And change `var pageCount=3;` to `var pageCount=7;`.